# Find equivalent nested object inside database using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, nested, entity-framework-6

I have `Patient` and `Institution` tables which I access using EF6

```
public class Patient
{
    [Key]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }
}

public class Institution
{
    [Key]
    public int InstitutionId { get; set; }
    public string InstitutionName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's say I create a `Patient` object by hand, something like that:

```
var newPatient = new Patient {
    PatientName = "Edward",
    Institution = new Institution {
        InstitutionName = "SomeInstitution"
    },
};
```

Now I want to check if I already have a patient named "Edward" in the institution "SomeInstitution".

My question is how to do that, for now I have this query:

```
public static Patient QueryFromAllProperties(MyDbContextcontext, Patient patient)
{
    return context.Patients
            .Where(p => p.PatientName == patient.PatientName)
            .SingleOrDefault();
}

var patient = QueryFromAllProperties(context, newPatient);
```

With that I can find if I have a patient with the same name as the one I created (`newPatient`), but I'm not sure how could I expand this query to check the institution too.

Note that I think I could just change the where to:

```
.Where(p => p.PatientName == patient.PatientName
            && p.Institution.InstitutionName == patient.Institution.InstitutionName)
```

This would work more or less, but it is not clean (this is just a simple example, in my code I have way more nested entities with more properties that I need to check), very boilerplate, and would break if `Institution` is `null`.

PS: note that I ignore `InstitutionId` since I don't want to compare the keys (I want to find the key in the db that configures that exactly object values) and I ignore `ICollection<Patient> Patients` since It is just a list to configure the many-to-one relation.

So, is there some other better way to do that?

Also, I would like to know how to handle that too in case of a many-to-many relation, so in that case, we can rewrite the tables as:

```
public class Patient
{
    [Key]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Institution> Institutions { get; set; }
}

public class Institution
{
    [Key]
    public int InstitutionId { get; set; }
    public string InstitutionName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
```

And in that case, from the `Institutions` part I would like to check if a `Patient` inside the database would contain all the institutions the object currently have (doesn't matter if the database `Patient` have more `Institutions` than the one I created.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) function might simplify it a little bit. `Any` is a function that will return `true` if there is any element in the collection that matches the condition you pass it.

```
var exists = context
    .Patients
    .Any(p => p.PatientName == patient.PatientName && 
         p.Institution.InstitutionName == patient.Institution.InstitutionName);
```

This will return a `bool` telling you whether it already exists instead of a `Patient` object as well.

Answer (score 1):

While with c#, a null object needs to be checked, it doesn't with Entity framework and Sql. Your query is translated to sql and run on the database server with an inner join.

For a many to many cardinality, either add the bridging table manually, or lookup how to do "fluent mapping" with EF.

And don't worry about trying to find shorter representations, or "cleaner" lines of code. Prioritise things the user will see, and the overall organisation of your code for maintainability: classes, functions.